# Remove an element that contains an specific String from a LinkedList

Tags: java, list, linked-list, iterator, contains

I am still a beginner in Java, I am trying to remove an element from a LinkedList, easy right? but my elements are sentences  the idea is to delete the element which contains an specific word, I am trying to use an Iterator... the problems seems to be that my Iterator compare the entire element and not word by word of each element. This isn't working, please help :)

```
private LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(  "Write  the item to remove" );
list.add("I like pizza");
list.add("love is in the air");



        for(Iterator<String> iterator =list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            if(iterator.next().contains((input))) { 
                iterator.remove(); 

                break;
                }

for(String x : list){
            System.out.printf("%s ", x)
       }
```

So if my input is love, my output should be "I like pizza".

Comment: Why is your list empty?

Comment: And what is your *actual* output?

Answer (score 1):

Try `if(iterator.next().toLowerCase.contains(input.toLowerCase))`

Also if you break within the loop it will only remove the first instance of the input rather than all occurrences.

`.contains` includes substrings so it will return true if, for example, "aaa" and "aaa b" are compared, so splitting the string isn't necessary.

Comment: very simple and clean solution - whereas i find the approach from NekoJimi also very educative...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to break up your string into words, and then iterate again over those words. Something like this should do the trick:

```
for(Iterator<String> iterator =list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) 
{
    String str = iterator.next();
    for (String word : str.split(" ")) // .split(" ") divides the string up into a String[], splitting on each occurrence of " " (actually a regex)
    {
        if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(input)) 
        {
            markForDelete(str); // if this word is a match, mark this string to be deleted somehow but DO NOT DELETE IT YET you'll die
            break;
        }
    }
}
actuallyDeleteStuff(); // delete everything that was marked by markForDelete(str)
```

This will delete any `String` from `list` where any of the words in that string are a case-insensitive match for `input`. You will need to provide for some implementation of marking items to delete, then deleting them; the reason I have done this is because if you try modifying  a collection while iterating over it, a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown and the program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
for(String x : list) {
  System.out.printf("%s ", x)
}
```

and you never emit an end-of-line character. Since the `System.out` stream is buffered, with auto-flushing behavior on newline, your output is just sitting in the output buffer, waiting to be flushed to the actual system device.

Solution: add

```
System.out.flush();
```

just after your for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your remove part is working fine. When you are printing use

```
for(String x : list)
    System.out.println(x);
```

Also, include what output or error you are getting. This will help to understand your problem better. Just noticed the question is 5 years old, I think i didn't saw the date earlier properly. Hopefully someone else will find it useful.